# Searching text in rich edit control (winapi 'riched20.dll')

Tags: windows, winapi

I am using `'riched20.dll'` windows built-in library to make a rich edit control for a WIN32 program. The program is simply a text editor, and I have now to implement finding-text functionality. The problem I am going with is how to iterate over the text in the rich edit control. I want to find the matched text in the control and highlight it (i.e. select it with blue background as if one selects it with mouse or shift key). I have searched the web without success.

I can do all that tasks in C#.NET easily. I am now stuck with Win32. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's very unspecific.  Use the Reference Source to see how the RichTextBox control does it.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Win32 rich edit control, to search for text, you need to use either [`EM_FINDTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788009.aspx) or [`EM_FINDTEXTEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788011.aspx). Or, if you are using Unicode, the variants with the `W` suffix.

To select text, use the [`EM_SETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb761661.aspx) message.

The [reference documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486019.aspx) for the rich edit control enumerates the entire capabilities of this control.

Comment: Thanks. How do I use them exactly?

Comment: The documentation (to which I linked) explains how to use these messages.